# How to make a text in a JLabel transparent?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `GridLayout`. I want the cells in the `GridLayout` to have an *"inner/invisible"* value, so I put a `JLabel` in each of the cells. But I don't want the text in `JLabels` to be visible. I tried `setVisible(false)`, but then the `MouseListener` doesn't work on them.
So, how can I make the text in a `JLabel` transparent?

Comment: Do you just want empty cells that respond to mouse events? Or do you need a JLabel there to later make text visible?

Comment: @BeUndead I actually wanted to have empty cells, with some values in them, that a user can't see, but can get the value from the cell when clicks on it. For example: my cell 6 is a visually empty cell with a value = "ABC", when user clicks on that cell, the console prints that value

Comment: And do you literally want the console (command line) to print, or do you want the result to be shown in the GUI somewhere?

Comment: It can be either of them. Assume that I want to get that `String` variable out of that cell and use it somewhere else.

Comment: If you just want to know how to make an invisible label, just make a JLabel with all spaces.  Then, use a new class you derive from JLabel, add a special field, and when the user clicks, add an event listener to show the hidden value.

Comment: @markspace Thanks! I totally forgot about that one, I think it will work for me.

Comment: There's probably at least half of a dozen good ways of doing this, and they depend on a lot of context you haven't given us.  Just put something together that is sensible and works with the other parts of your code.

Comment: As markspace says, there's a lot of approaches here.  Another option would be to extend `JLabel` and just `setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));` (transparent text).

Comment: @BeUndead That's actually a better option for me, I searched a lot for how to give a text a transparent color and couldn't find much

Comment: It sounds more like you're mixing "view" with data - I'd consider having some kind of look up mechanism which could take the component which was clicked and determine it's value either from a model or the component itself (such as using a custom component)